# How do I create a deployable ActiveX control?

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2010, activex, code-signing, activexobject

I have written a simple ActiveX control using Visual Studio 2010.  I have registered this control on my development machine using regasm, and I can invoke the control in IE using Javascript's `new ActiveXObject("...")` functionality.

However, I now need to prepare my ActiveX control for deployment to the customer, and this is where I need assistance.

I would like to package the control so that IE simply prompts the user in the infobar to install the control.

I understand that I will need to obtain a code signing certificate so that my ActiveX control will be trusted.

My question is, what are the steps I need to work through to turn my code into a deployable unit of software?  What role do CAB files, INF files, OSD files etc play in this?  And how do I package up my control using Visual Studio 2010?

If there are any existing walk-through guides out there, I would be very grateful to be pointed in their direction - I haven't been able to find a comprehensive and easy-to-follow guide myself.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your ActiveX is a single file then you can have it downloaded to the users by setting it in the object tag

```
<object classid="clsid:your-dll-classid" codebase="http://someurl/your.dll" ></object>
```

IE will download the file if it doesn't exists on the user's system.

Answer (score 0):

To know more about packaging ActiveX control see 
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751974%28VS.85%29.aspx)